# C++ using .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++

I am completely new to C++ and wanted to get a hang on the using my functions in programs by extracting them from an organized file. I do not understand why my code (see below) does not work, I tried to find an answer but really couldn't. Anyway, here's the code, hope it helps.

My .h file:

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MYMATH_H_INCLUDED
#endif // MYMATH_H_INCLUDED

int sum (int,int);
```

My.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myMath.h"

int sum(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}
```

My main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myMath.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a, b;
   cin >> a;
   cin >> b;
   cout << sum(a,b);
}
```

and finally the error block:

```
||=== Build: Debug in using my functions (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\Barcanjo\Desktop\Coding\using my functions\main.cpp|11|undefined 
reference to `sum(int, int)'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: How are you trying to compile this? Can you give us what you pass to `g++`? (also your header guards are doing nothing at the moment, you should put the `#endif` at the end of the file)

Comment: Are you sure you're linking your .cpp file? Also, #endif is normally the last line in the file although that will have a benign effect here.

Comment: You are implementing a multiple-inclusion guard wrongly in your header.  The `#endif` should go all the way at the end, so that the whole content of the file is within the scope of the `#ifdef`.  But that's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: The `#endif` in your .h file is wrongly located. It should be at the very end of the file.

Comment: You have obvious typos (no open quote on one include), misused include guards (the `endif` goes after the body of the include file), and you don't provide your compile line (which is probably the source of the problem, forgetting to compile `my.cpp` into the final result).

Comment: You are not using the include guard properly.  The `#endif` should be the last line of the file.  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard]

Comment: Off-topic:  You should get in the habit of providing variable names in your parameters.  If your really nice, you add comments describing the functions purpose and requirements of the parameters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews hey there, so I should get red of the a,b in the parameters section? But then how would one supply values to it? (Sorry again for trivial questions)

Comment: You should have parameters in your prototype or declaration: `int sum (int a, int b);`, not `int sum(int, int);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are not linking the my.cpp object with main.cpp.

The following should solve the problem:

```
$ g++ main.cpp my.cpp -o my
$ ./my
```

Comment: Alright, I'm feeling dumb, where does this go exactly? Is there a change I must do in the compiler settings? I'm using Code:: Blocks. Sorry for the really trivial questions

Comment: @Barcanjo I don't use Code::Blocks, but you can open a shell in the directory of your source code and execute the above commands to compile your code. Code::Blocks is probably compiling the current open file alone...

Comment: I added the files to the project (from the IDE interface) and it fixed it. Thank you for helping :) Another question, is code:: Blocks bad or something alike? just wondering since you don't use it and from the research, I've done I got the impression it was a good IDE.

Comment: @Barcanjo Glad to help :). It' really just about taste - I prefer Visual Studio on Windows or Jetbrains CLion on Linux.

Comment: I see, I tried visual studio but found it quite slow :( thanks again for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

You header is wrong. You need:

```
#ifndef MYMATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MYMATH_H_INCLUDED

int sum (int,int);

#endif // MYMATH_H_INCLUDED
```

In your current code, the include guard doesn't actually guard anything.

Or even better, just use this:

```
#pragma once

int sum (int,int);
```

(Random people will jump in and say this is not standard C++, but you can safely ignore them. `#pragma once` is the de-facto standard way to protect header files against multiple inclusion.)

Now to the build error. It would seem to me that you are not building the `myMath.cpp` file at all. Make sure you have added that file to your project in your IDE, since it's the file that actually implements the `sum()` function.

If you are not using an IDE and you are building manually, then either build all your source files at once:

```
g++ main.cpp myMath.cpp
```

Or compile the files into object files and link them at the end:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c myMath.cpp
g++ main.o myMath.o
```

You can use the `-o` flag to specify the name of the resulting executable. By default, it's `a.out`.

Comment: Hey there, changed it to pragma since it's way more practical! About the build error, I believe it is in my project, at least in my IDE it appears in the same file (sources) as the main.cpp.

Comment: @Barcanjo Make sure you actually added the file to the project. Many IDEs will allow you to open and edit files that are actually not part of the project. Which means you can edit them, but they won't get compiled.

Comment: @Barcanjo I haven't used code::blocks in a long time, but IIRC, right-click the project name, then select "Add files" and then select myMath.h and myMath.cpp and then confirm with OK.

Comment: Ohh, so even though the file is in the same folder in the IDE (I'm using code:: Blocks), I need to actually add it to the project. Just did this and it fixed it, thank you for helping (and all the others as well). Just a final question, it's bad practice to use .cpp files in headers, right?

Comment: @Barcanjo Yes. Never include .cpp files in headers. This will result in multiple definitions when the header file that includes a cpp file is used by several other files. In fact, never `#include` a .cpp file ever, period. There's some rare cases where this is done, but in general, don't do it.

Comment: Alright, thanks again for the fix and tips :D have a great night!

Comment: @Barcanjo Thanks. Don't forget to mark the answer that solved your problem as "accepted" (click the checkmark under the answer score). Otherwise, your question will remain as unsolved on the site.